# Get time for system default timezone

Tags: date, timezone

When logging in to remote machine X, by default, `date` will give the time in the local timezone:

```
$ date
Mon Nov 17 22:45:47 CET 2014
```

Note that `TZ` is not set:

```
$ export | grep TZ
$
```

So, I set `TZ` to my own local timezone for every machine I'm on:

```
$ export TZ=/usr/share/zoneinfo/Canada/Eastern
$ date
Mon Nov 17 16:46:13 EST 2014
```

The question is, once I have this set, **how do I get the time for the system default timezone**, i.e. the timezone that applies if I, as a user, do not manually set `TZ`?  *Unsetting* `TZ` gives me the UTC time, which is not what I seek:

```
$ TZ= date
Mon Nov 17 21:47:13 UTC 2014
```

Interestingly, `TZ= date` gives UTC time, even when I didn't yet set `TZ` to anything; yet when I didn`t yet set `TZ` to anything, a simple `date` gave the date in the system default timezone...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try unsetting the `TZ` variable (which is different from setting it to `""`):

```
$ (date; export TZ=/usr/share/zoneinfo/Canada/Eastern; date; unset TZ; date)
Tue Nov 18 03:25:25 IST 2014
Mon Nov 17 16:55:25 EST 2014
Tue Nov 18 03:25:25 IST 2014
```

Note how I tried it in a subshell, so that my current shell remains unaffected.

Comment: Interesting.  I was not aware that unsetting is different from setting it to empty.

Comment: @gerrit Usually in scripts there's not much difference. But for a few variables which control the behaviour of programs, like `TZ`, `POSIXLY_CORRECT`, `HISTTIMEFORMAT`, it does matter.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to view the system clock time zone by catting this file:  `/etc/sysconfig/clock`.

Comment: [This](http://dev.chetankjain.net/2012/04/fixing-date-time-and-zone-on-rhel-6.html) is a good article on the subject.

Comment: Is this distribution-specific? I don't have `/etc/sysconfig` on my Debian servers.

Comment: @Barmar `/etc/sysconfig` is a Red Hat thing.